# How to catch specific error in any template in Django?

Tags: django, templates, exception, middleware

I want to catch custom exception that I raise in a method called from base.html. When it happens, I need to redirect user to another page. Where is the best place to do this?

Below is simplified example of code to show the problem

base.html:

```
{% if something %}{{ widget_provider.get_header }}{% endif %}
```

widget_providers.py

```
class SpecificWidgetProvider(BaseWidgetProvider):
    def get_header(self):
        if self.user.is_anonimous():
            raise AuthenticationRequired()
        return third_party_api.get_top_secret_header_widget()
```

AuthenticationRequired exception may be raised by many parts of my site (most time in views), and I want to keep the handler in one place. So I created a middleware to catch this type of exception.

middleware.py

```
def process_exception(request, exception):
    if isinstance(exception, AuthenticationRequired):
        return redirect('accounts:login')
```

But I've found that class based views may leave the template rendering phase for later. They just return TemplateResponse instance, and Django's request handler (get_response() in django.core.handlers.base) calls response.render() outside of all middlewares stack. So now my middleware can't catch the exception. Maybe it is better to call get_header() from context processor, but this does not help too.

Comment: can you not call a new view and use try except - where you do a return redirect() on except ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you question. Could you please explain?

Comment: Wherever you wish do catch the exception in template, call a url {% url view_name %} , and in the view have 
try:
  #your logic 
except:
  return redirect('new_url')

Comment: As you can see in my example, the output is in base.html. So all my views use this base template. I'd not like to add this try/except to each view in the project. I want to keep this logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problme by prefetching the data within try/except in process_template_response() in the same middleware, and moved error processing to common private method. This allows me to keep error processing in the same place.

```
def process_template_response(self, request, response)
    try:
        widget_provider.get_header()
    except AuthenticationRequired:
        response = self._process_auth_required()
        # Bind render() method that just returns itself, because we must
        # return TemplateResponse or similar here.
        def render(self):
            return self
        response.render = types.MethodType(render, response)
        return response

def process_exception(self, request, exception):
    if isinstance(exception, AuthenticationRequired):
        return self._process_auth_required()

def _process_auth_required(self):
    return redirect('accounts:login')
```